# move and maximize QuickTime Player window

Tags: c#, quicktime

I am wondering how can I move and maximize a QuickTime window from C#, I can use this code for regular windows like explorer window

```
SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 500, 400, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);             
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

but QuickTime seems to have a different type of window system.

Comment: Do you mean quicktime player's window? Because `quicktime window` seems (by quick googling) not a commonly used thing .

Comment: Yes, I mean Quicktime player window, (processname = QuickTimePlayer), how can I move and maximize the window from my c# program?